# How can I fix that call function getMoney

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

My problem is when I check my total money after second times call function `getMoney`. That shows me the wrong total. I want to invest in my account that will be plus my new total.

```
var cash = 1000;
var total = cash;

/*get money */
function getMoney() {
    var Money = prompt("How much do you want to get money: ","0");
    total = Number(cash) - Number(Money);
    if(Money <= cash){
        document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = Money+" $ loading.";

        var Print = confirm("Do you want to printer?");
        var Time = setTimeout(function(){
            if(Print==true) {
                document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = "Printer is  preparing.";
            } else {
                document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = "Thanks you for saving Natural.";
            }
        }, 3000);
    } else {
         document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = "Total money"+cash+" No limit.";
    }
}

function investIn() {
    var investIn = prompt("How much do you want to invest in your account: ");
    total = total + Number(investIn);
    document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = total + "your account..";
    var Print = confirm("Do you want to printer?");

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(Print == true) {
            document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = "Before invest in: "+(total-Number(investIn))+"<br>"+" İnvest in total: "+invest+"<br>"+"After invest in total your account: "+total;
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = "Thanks you for saving Natural.";
        }
    }, 3000);
}

/* control money */
function accountBalance() {
    document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML = total+" your account.";
}
```

Comment: Please add your html too and try to create snippet

Comment: Please explain or put your html code aswell

Comment: Can you provide step of function calls you made?